# How to input gem5 trace file into OMNET++ framework?

Tags: simulation, trace, omnet++, gem5

I have simulated CHSTONE benchmark by Gem5 simulator and got a trace file with it. after that I need to simulate this trace file in OMNET++ and get the result.
How can I do this and how can I use this file as an input in OMNET++?